# Creating new layer group in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, group-layer

I am in the process of learning ArcGIS Desktop, and as I was working through the tutorial provided to me, I was told to create a new layer group by right-clicking on "layers" in a new blank map, and choosing "new layer group" from the menu.

My issue is that it does not work, it does respond (screen twitches) but it doesn't show a new window for it.

This is on ArcGIS 10.5.1, and on a personal laptop.

I am looking for suggestions for a workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should just make a new, empty group layer in your table of contents. You should see 'New Group Layer'.

[image]

You can drag other layers into this group layer and collectively toggle them on/off as needed.

As a workaround you can always CTRL + click multiple layers, right click one of them, and select 'Group'. This will create a Group Layer automatically rather than creating an empty one.

Comment: It should do that, but for some reason it isn't.

Comment: @ElizB does your Table of Contents change at all? Have you tried restarting ArcMap and/or your machine? ArcMap can be pretty finicky

Comment: i tried rebooting multiple times, table of contents does not change at all.

Comment: Hmm that is odd behavior. As a workaround you can always ctrl + click multiple layers, then right click one of them and select 'Group'. This will make a Group Layer automatically rather than making an empty one.

Comment: That would be an excellent workaround. Thanks!! Can you add that in the answer? :)

Comment: Awesome! Let me edit my answer right now. @ElizB

Comment: @ElizB Check if you have the TOC set to "List by Drawing Order" (the 4 buttons at the top of the TOC window). Other settings may not show group layers.